# How can i list all tables used in a datastage project?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, datastage

I have , for example, PROJECT 'School' with n jobs (load_student,load_teacher,..)

i need a list of all tables used in each job of project 'School'. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reasonable request but there is no DataStage functionality for this - sorry. 
A possible (I didn't say easy) workaround could be to export the project and parse the export file. But keep in mind the tables might be "hidden" in different locations like BeforeSQL, AfterSQL, some user-defined SQL and so on. So you might get SQL Statements and you have to parse those again to get the tables.

Another approach might be to set up database monitoring to capture all SQLs or table accesses.